# Why is my addition app giving wrong answer?

Tags: java, android

I tried creating an addition app that takes input of 2 numbers and displays their sum. The app is giving the wrong answer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edtTxt1;
EditText edtTxt2;
TextView txt;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    edtTxt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edtTxt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer_textView);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(edtTxt1.getText().toString());
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(edtTxt1.getText().toString());
            int result = num1 + num2;
            txt.setText(""+result);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing in the logs? Do num1 and num2 actually possess values?

Comment: Could you share some input/output data?

Comment: int num2 = Integer.parseInt(__edtTxt1__.getText().toString());  You should be careful first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting input number in both variables from the same edit text please update it like bellow

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(edtTxt1.getText().toString());
 int num2 = Integer.parseInt(edtTxt2.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

'in your button click you are getting booth numbers from same edittexts like'

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(edtTxt1.getText().toString());
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(edtTxt1.getText().toString());
```

'correct it'
'hope you get the solution'

Comment: you are doing the same, might need to edit edtTxt1 to edtTxt2 in second line.

Comment: @KaranMer I think that's the point, they're telling OP what they're doing wrong, not how to fix it

Comment: i just  point out the mistake not correct it coz it was so simple

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edtTxt1;
EditText edtTxt2;
TextView txt;
Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        edtTxt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edtTxt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer_textView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(edtTxt1.getText().toString());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(edtTxt2.getText().toString());
                int result = num1 + num2;
                txt.setText(""+result);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I hope this will solve your issue. let me know if anything.

Comment: While posting the correct code is helpful, could you please explain **how** it helps OP so it helps them avoid making the same mistake in future?